# C# Reading a logfile into a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datatable, filereader

I am trying to import a logfile and display it in a listview in a grid format ( much like excel ). I am wondering what may be the best approach to take with this. Filereader and a data table possibly ? I have not programmed anything like this before. This is a windows form project.

Any advice on the issue would be a great help.

**EDIT2:**

Example of the logfile:

```
 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
 i d   =   1 0 0 1
 P a r a m e t e r   1   =   E N A B L E D
 P a r a m e t e r   2   =   D I S A B L E D
 P a r a m e t e r   3   =   N U L L
 P a r a m e t e r   4   =   N U L L
 P a r a m e t e r   5   =   S U C C E S S  
 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
```

This the repeats with different Data.

I would like this to be read in and displayed in a listview under the different headings id, name etc

This application is limited to the use of .NET 3.5 also.

Comment: Is this a WinForm project?  WPF?  What is the format of the log file?

Comment: Yep. Sorry, ive updated the question

Comment: Filereader and data table sound good, is your file consistently delimited?

Comment: Can you provide file format..

Comment: Ive updated the question again. its a .log filetype

Comment: Is there some kind of consistent delimiter between each log entry?  Or do they all have the same number of lines?  Or do they all start with the same key name?

Comment: Yes sorry. They all start with ID followed by the other parameters. So Id followed by the next 3 lines would be what is read for each row. This would be split across 4 columns in the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be to read your file in one line at a time using a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and placing the data in a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

Edit: The following code works for me on a project targeted to .Net 2.0 and assumes the name of your DataGridView is dataGridView1

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\jdudley\file.txt");
// Will be incremented every time ID shows up so it must started at -1 so we don't
// try and start inserting at 1.
int rowIndex = -1;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    string[] parsedLine = line.Split(new char[] { '=' });
    if(!this.dataGridView1.Columns.Contains(parsedLine[0]))
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(parsedLine[0],parsedLine[0]);
    }
    if (parsedLine[0].Trim().Equals("id"))
    {
        rowIndex++;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    }
    dataGridView1[parsedLine[0], rowIndex].Value = parsedLine[1];
}
```

Comment: This was my first guess also. Unfortunatly I believe that DataGridView is .NET 4.0. I need to stay with 3.5

Comment: I use a DataGridView in a project targeted for 2.0

Comment: I may have read something wrong if that is the case. Could someone clear that up ?

Comment: It's supported. Here is the documentation for the version for 3.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.90%29.aspx You can click on the other versions link on to the right of the current and see the documentation for the previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for the code. The last line is giving me trouble though. After debugging it seems that its skipping the last if statement when it needs to enter it because `parsedLine[]` is empty

Comment: Could this be because the file has a trailing newline statement?

Comment: Possibly, I will have to look into it and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, Ive tested it with another logfile and it enters the loop and updates rowIndex to 0. Im getting a `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` error however now on the same line.

Comment: The code works for me given a the format you supplied. Are you sure the log file conforms to this format? The only reason you would get this is if there wasn't an equals in the line. Thus meaning there the parsedLine would only have a length of 1.

Comment: Ah my mistake. I have updated the question with an a snippet of the correct logfile. The logfile contains spaces between characters.

Comment: Are you trying to understand what my code is doing or just coping and pasting? The line that is all equal signs will break my code since it assumes that all lines will simply be data lines. You will need to detect these and skip over them.

Comment: Yes I am understanding it. I was looking at the wrong logfile which didnt contain that line of equals. I will work around this with a check. Thank you for your effort in helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to show one row in the list per line in the log file, I'd simply use `File.ReadAllLines` to read the file, then use a dictionary to store the key value pairs for each log entry:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> entries = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> entry = null;
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(logFilePath))
{
    string[] fields = line.Split('=');
    if (fields.Length > 1)
    {
        if (fields[0].Trim() == "id")
        {
            if (entry != null) entries.Add(entry);
            entry = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        if (entry != null) entry[fields[0].Trim()] = fields[1].Trim();
    }
}
if (entry != null) entries.Add(entry);
```